# how to call a land line through a website?

Tags: php, voip

i have seen a few sites like prankdial that lets you spoof your number and make a call to a persons cell or home number how is this being done from a website?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use COM's to access your local skype installation to dial a number for you, take a look at this library:

- [PHPLibrary](https://github.com/fujimoto/php-skype)
- [Skype COM's API Guide](http://forum.skype.com/index.php?showtopic=47585)
- [Skype Developers](http://developer.skype.com/)

You can perform mosts tasks via COM's such as calls, chat, contacts and send messages:

```
$skype = new COM("Skype4COM.Skype");
$skype->sendSms("+1234567890", "SMS text goes here");
```

You can download the Native

Comment: Did you click the *HUGE* Documentation link? http://www.twilio.com/docs/howto/clicktocall

Comment: that is huge? its a few pages

Comment: The size of the link on the front page, not the size of the documentation!